# Existence of a limit for the solution of the equation $y'=\sin y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

> We look at the equation $y'=\sin(y)$, if $y$ is a solution which maintain 
>   $y(0) \in (\pi,2\pi)$, without solving the equation, prove that the limit 
>   $\lim_{x\to\infty} y(x) $ exist and calculate it.

Is it enough quoting the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for proving existence and drawing the graph for calculating the limit? (I do not see any other way to find the limit without calculating it)

Comment: I will try dividing by $\sin (y)$ and do separation of variables (note $y(x) \in (\pi,2\pi)$ for all $x$: it follows from uniqueness)

Comment: @JohnMa but separation of variables means solving the equation, which i can not do

Comment: maybe the question is set in the theory of qualitative analysis of differential equations, what is beyond my actual knowledge about the topic

Comment: Sooo... You know/assume that $\pi<y(0)<2\pi$ and that $\sin<0$ on this interval hence $y(\ )$ is decreasing and never "crosses" the fixed point $\pi$ hence $y(\ )$ has a limit and this limit is $____$.

Comment: @Masacroso well this question came from a differential equation test last year, so i will rather think it is in our power to solve it :)

Answer (score 2):

If $y(0) \in (\pi,2\pi)$, then $y(x) \in (\pi,2\pi)$ for all $x$. This follows from uniqueness of ODE.

Now $y'(x) = \sin (y(x))<0$ since $y(x) \in y(x) \in (\pi,2\pi)$, then it must have a limit since it is bounded.

Let's call this limit $a$. Then $a\in [\pi,2\pi)$. We claim that $a = \pi$. If not, then $a>\pi$ and we have

$$ \sin y(x) \le C:=\max\{ \sin y(0), \sin a\} <0$$

and thus for all $x$,

$$ y(x) = y(0)+ \int_0^x \sin y(s) ds \le y(0) +Cx.$$

But this is impossible as $y(x) \ge \pi$ (note $C<0$).

Comment: bounded solution means it exist ? can you explain please. can't a solution be trigonometric function?

Comment: Let $f: [0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ be a decreasing function and $f\ge C$ for some $C$, then show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exists. This is not difficult to show, and I think I will leave it to you. @david007killer

Comment: Yes, it is easy to show it is decreasing, my bad. Should have thought a little before i posted that.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a vertical $y$-axis and adorn it with small line elements having slope $\sin y$. Then the elements at $y=k\pi$, $k\in{\mathbb Z}$ have slope $0$, indicating that the constant functions $y(x)\equiv k\pi$ are solutions. By the Uniqueness Theorem no other solution can cross these horizontal lines. In particular a solution with $y(0)\in\ ]\pi,2\pi[\ $ has to stay forever in the interval $\ ]\pi,2\pi[\ $. Now look at the slopes of the drawn line elements in this interval: They are all negative. This means that the solution will be monotonically decreasing forever, hence have a limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}y(x)=:\alpha\geq\pi$. It follows that $$0=\lim_{x\to\infty}y'(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin\bigl(y(x)\bigr)=\sin\alpha\ ,$$
hence $\alpha=\pi$.

Comment: Just a theoretical question(which can sound stupid), can i use the graph as part of a solution ?

Comment: @david007killer: You wrote in your question that you hoped for a "qualitative" argument. If you think my answer does accomplish that use the described drawing to support your solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer.** $\lim_{t\to\infty} y(t)=\pi$.

In order to show this we need the following result:

**Lemma.** *If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable, $\xi<\eta$, are two consecutive zeros of $f$, i.e., $f(\xi)=f(\eta)=0$ and $f(x)\ne 0$, for all $x\in(\xi,\eta)$, then, for all $\zeta\in(\xi,\eta)$, the initial value problem
$$
x'=f(x), \quad x(0)=\zeta,\tag{1}
$$
possesses a global solution. Further, if $f(x)>0$, for all $x\in(\xi,\eta)$, then, $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=\eta$, while if $f(x)<0$, for all $x\in(\xi,\eta)$, then, $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=\xi$.*

*Sketch of proof of the Lemma.*

Step 1. We now, from Picard-Lindelöf, that the above IVP enjoys existence and uniqueness in some interval $(a,b)$. Also, we can define the maximum interval $(A,B)$, where a solution $\varphi$ of this IVP exists.

Step 2. $\xi<\varphi(t)<\eta$, for all $t\in(A,B)$. If for example $\varphi(t_1)\ge \eta$, for some $t_1\in(A,B)$, the there would be a $t_2\in (A,B)$, where $\varphi(t_2)=\eta$, and hence $\varphi$ would satisfy the IVP
$$
x'=f(x), \quad x(t_1)=\eta. \tag{2}
$$
But $\psi(t)\equiv\eta$ is a solution of $(2)$, and by Uniqueness, it is THE solution, and hence $\varphi(t)=\psi(t)=\eta$, for all $t$. Contradiction.

Step 3. The fact that $\xi<\varphi(t)<\eta$, for as long a $\varphi$ exists, implies the the maximum interval is the whole real line, i.e., $\varphi$ is a global solution.

Step 4. Assume for example, as in the OP, that $f(x)<0$, for all $x\in (\xi,\eta)$. Then $\varphi'(t)=f\big(\varphi(t)\big)<0$, and hence $\varphi$ is strictly decreasing, and hence its limit, as $t\to\infty$ exists, and 
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\varphi(t)\ge \xi.
$$ 
Assume that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\varphi(t)=\ell< \xi.$ Then we would have that 
$$
\zeta\ge\varphi(t)\ge\ell>\xi,
$$ 
for all $t\in\mathbb R$. Set $\omega=\min_{x\in [\ell,\zeta]}f(x).$ Then
$$
\varphi'(t)=f\big(\varphi(t)\big)\le \omega <0,
$$
for all $t\ge 0$, and hence
$$
\varphi(t)=\varphi(0)+\int_0^t f\big(\varphi(s)\big)\,ds\le \zeta+t\omega\to-\infty,
$$
as $t\to\infty$. Contradiction. Thus $\lim_{t\to\infty}\varphi(t)=\xi$.